# How to build a RESTful webservice using ServiceStack? ServiceStack Samples not working

Tags: web-services, servicestack

The samples given at servicestack are not working. I am new to servicestack.I want to build RESTful web service with service stack.PLease direct me in proper direction.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue you're running into is but the [ServiceStack.Examples projects](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/) do work. They were all developed in VS.NET and are [deployed on servicestack.net](http://www.servicestack.net) Linux Server.

The [Razor Rockstars](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars) example project is deployed on [razor.servicestack.net](http://razor.servicestack.net/).

The [Social Bootstrap API (MVC + Bootstrap + Backbone) project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi) is deployed on a windows server on AppHarbor at [bootstrapapi.apphb.com](http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/).